# Value of object in array does not update in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Mongoose model with the following property:

```
new Schema({
 votes: [{tag: String, votes: Number}]
})
```

I try to change the votes field inside the object but after I call .save(), the value is not updated. I have tried using:

```
post.markModified('votes')
```

The code where it is called:

```
let post = await Post.findById(req.body.postId) //Express request

for(let item in post.votes){ //votes is the array as in the model
        if(item.tag === tag){
            item.votes += 1
            break
        }
    }

post.save({}, (err, doc) => {
        //Other stuff    
    })
```

where post is the model, but this also does not work. How can I save it after changing the value?

Comment: Can you provide us code in which you are trying to «change the votes field inside the object»?

Comment: @AlexZeDim Have added it in the question

Comment: `if(item.tag === tag)` are you sure that equation truly equal? I mean, if it does, why you `break` statement then? Of course it won't trigger `.save()` and also, try to `.save()` it, without callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I seem to have found an answer to this, has to use the update function:

```
Post.updateOne({ _id: post.id, 'votes.tag': tag }, { $set: { 'votes.$.votes': 1 } }, (err, raw) => {})
```

Answer (score 0):

`.save()` does not update the array.

You would have to update the array with the query.

```
let post = await Post.findById(req.body.postId) //Express request

for(let item in post.votes){ //votes is the array as in the model
        if(item.tag === tag){
            item.votes += 1
            break
        }
    }

// update the votes aray with the modified votes array:
Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.postId, {votes: votes}, (err, doc => {
// do your stuff
}))
```

Comment: He is dealing with `object` not with `array`, take a look at `for (let item in object)` it's not `for (let item of array)`

Comment: Yes i know. This would update the whole array.
Also I was trying not to do it with mongoose query because he would have to change all of his api.
Also in your answer change `response.json` to `res.json` as you are using `res` in the async function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it does the same logic as your are using above, find blog post by `ID` and check does field named `tag` in object `votes` `$exits` if it does, then it increment your field `likes` value by +1.

```
express.method("/:postId", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const updatedBlog = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
              _id: req.body.postId,
              "votes.tag": { $exists: true }
            },
            {
                $inc: { "item.votes": 1 }
            },
            { new: true } //to return the new document
        );
        res.json(updatedBlog);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).end();
    }
});
```